# $E[e^x]=e^{E[x]}$ holds?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

$E$ is the expectation and $x$ is the random variable. If it holds, how to prove? If it fails, how to calculate $E[e^x]$ in a simplified way?

Comment: just take $x$ as the coin toss random variable that takes $-1$ and $1$, each with equal probability. Then, the RHS is 1 and LHS is $\cosh(1).$

Comment: If you know $\,E[x^n]\,$ for all $\,n\,$ then use the power series expansion for $\,e^x.$

Comment: The equation holds iff $X$ is a constant(with probability $1$). So it  appears that you never tried any example.

Answer (score 2):

[Jensen's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) states that if $X$ is a random variable and $\phi$ is a convex function, then $$\phi(\mathbb{E}[X]) \le \mathbb{E}[\phi(X)].$$ Furthermore, if $\phi$ is strictly convex, then equality can only hold if $X$ is a constant random variable.

In particular, if you let $\phi(x) = e^x$, you get that $e^{\mathbb{E}[X]} \le \mathbb{E}[e^X]$. Since $e^x$ is strictly convex, equality will only hold if $X$ is a constant random variable.

The general formula for calculating $\mathbb{E}[\phi(X)]$ is $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(x)f(x)\,dx$ where $f(x)$ is the probability density function of $X$. So if you know the p.d.f. of $X$, then you can try to calculate $\mathbb{E}[e^X] = \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^xf(x)\,dx$.

Answer (score 1):

By [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality) we have that $$e^{E[X]}\leq E[e^X]$$

We can have equality, say for example if $X$ is constant. We can also have $E[e^X]-e^{E[X]}$ as large as we want. For example let $X$ be $-M$ with probability $1/2$ and $M$ with probability $1/2$. Then $E[e^X]-e^{E[X]}=\cosh(M)-1$ which can be made as big as you want.